# Download articles in joomla

Tags: joomla

Lets say,if I add a new article in joomla website and I want to download that article in pdf file on the front-end of the site. How can I achieve it?

Is it possible if I add a new article in joomla and in the front-end, visitors of the page can download that article in pdf file? How can I do it? Is there any solution to my problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/1128/120

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can use [Phoca PDF](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/phoca-pdf/).

It is a free extension. Enjoy!

Comment: is there a place I can find a tutorial on how to integrate Phoca PDF in my Joomla. I have downloaded and installed it but the PDF option is not among the Print and Email options on a single article.

Comment: You can see the [documentation](http://www.phoca.cz/documentation/category/87-phocapdf) and the [forum dedicated](http://www.phoca.cz/forum/viewforum.php?f=37). See also the Phoca PDF plugins.